# Can't crawl Data from Yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, request

I doing crawl data from Yahoo Financail. I have searched link:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BVH?period1=923729900&period2=1618039708&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true.

```
def createLink(symbol,table):
    s = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BVH?period1=923729900&period2=1618039708&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    return s.replace("BVH",symbol).replace("history",table)

def getData(symbol,table):
    URL = createLink(symbol,table)
    web = requests.get(URL)
    if web.status_code == 200:
      reader = pd.read_csv(URL)
    else:
      reader = pd.DataFrame({"Data":[],"Dividends":[],"Stock Splits":[]})
    return reader
def history(symbol):
    history_close = getData(symbol,'history')
    if history_close.empty:
      return history_close
    divend = getData(symbol,'div')
    stock = getData(symbol,'split')
    x = pd.merge(divend,stock, how="outer", on="Date")
    data = pd.merge(history_close,x, how="outer", on="Date")    
    return data
df = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/symbolNYSE.xlsx")
count = 0
count_fail = 0

for i in range(0,len(df["Symbol"])):
    try:
      count += 1
      print(df["Symbol"][i],count)
      a = history(df["Symbol"][i])
      if not a.empty:
        a.to_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/GetCloseYahoo/"+df["Symbol"][i]+".xlsx")
    except:
      count_fail+=1
      pass


print("success:", count)
print("fail:", count_fail)
```

I am using python, request, pandas on Jupiter to crawl it.
The errors:

- Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 12
- Key error

Start, i can crawl about 100 - 200 company. Then the program will error by any Symbol company. Finally, i wait a minute i can run repeat it, the program is not error.

What is the reason? Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe the site doesn't want bots crawling around its data and does things to frustrate them. I don't see how you can reasonably expect an answer. You tell us that your code (which you haven't shown) has no error -- so what exactly is your question? All we know is that you aren't happy with how this unknown code is behaving. If you want help, please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm so sorry. But i edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code -- but what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: When i crawl 1 symbol, it isn't error. But crawl about 100-200 symbol, it will bug. :( When i check 1 symbol error. It run

Comment: I update the error message.

Comment: Could you point which line it is failing? or attach a full traceback

Comment: The site you're talking to has some rate limiting on the number of times you're allowed to call it.  No one here can tell you how to get around those limits, contact the site owners.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it limit my request. My solve is use delay to request. And the result is good.